# node.js - get value of promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
let { errors } = otherValdations(data);

withDB(async (db) => {
    return Promise.all([

       ..code...

    ]).then(() => {
        return {
            errors,
            isValid: isEmpty(errors),
        }
    })
}, res).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

How can I get 'result' variable to be the value of the object returned in promise.all? This is the code for withDB function:

```
const withDB = async (operations, res) => {
try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    const db = client.db('app');

    await operations(db);

    client.close();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error connecting to db', error});
  }
};
```

Comment: What does `withDB()` do?  It is what determines what `result` is so we can't really comment without seeing the code for `withDB()`.

Comment: I have added the code for withDB

Comment: If you can use `async`, then `await` is clearer and simpler than continuing to use `.then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify `withDB()` so that it returns the value you want:

```
const withDB = async (operations, res) => {
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true });
        const db = client.db('app');

        let result = await operations(db);

        client.close();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error connecting to db', error});
        throw error;
    }
}
```

In your `catch()` handler, you also need to do something so that your calling code can distinguish the error path where you've already sent an error response from the case where you're resolved with the value.  I don't know exactly how you want that to work, but I put in a `throw error` so that it will reject the returned promise and the caller can see that.

I notice from your error handling that you are assuming all possible errors are causing by an error connecting to the DB.  That is not the case here.  If `operations(db)` rejects, that will also hit your `catch`.

Answer (score -1):

`Promise.all` returns an array with the results. So you either have to loop over the results or access them directly by supplying an index.

Comment: I don't think you're answering what the OP's actual problem is.  They are asking about `result` which is the resolved value from `withDB()`, not from `Promise.all()`.

Comment: That isn't reason to downvote. Maybe it does answer the question - we don't know. OP should ask a clearer question.

Comment: I didn't downvote.  That was someone else.  IMO, the question is now completely clear.